# Finding values in a space that matches a relational query

Tags: algorithms

Assume we have 26 vectors ${A,B,C,....,Z}$ all have 1 million integers. given a query:
$$
\vec{query} = (r_a, r_b, r_c, ..., r_c)
$$
I want to find a match vector $\vec{m_{1 \times 26}} = (a, b, c, ..., z)$ that satisfies the following criterias:

$$
a \in A, b \in B, c \in C, ..., z \in Z \\
\text{and} \\
r_{a} = \frac{a}{\sum_{\theta \in m}{\theta}}, r_{b} = \frac{b}{\sum_{\theta \in m}{\theta}}, ..., r_{z} = \frac{z}{\sum_{\theta \in m}{\theta}}
$$
in which $\sum_{\theta \in m}{\theta}$ is basically sum of the values in vector `m`. In other words, let say given the amount of share each $a, b, c, ..., z$ has in my math vector `m`, I want to find the elements. Of course, one yet not feasible solution is checking all ${(10^6)^{26}}$ possible combinations and check if there exists any match. There could be multiple answers, but any of them is fine.

**Example:**
Let say all ${A,B,C,....,Z}$ are equal to each other and contains elements between $1$ and $10^6$ like $\{1,2,3,...,10^6\}$. given query $\vec{query} = (\frac{1}{26}, \frac{1}{26}, \frac{1}{26}, ..., \frac{1}{26})$, $m$ is one of the many possible solutions:
$$
\vec{m} = (1,1,1,...,1).
$$

My question is, what could be the fastest algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: Do you really mean the query and $m$ to be a set, or do you intend them to be an ordered array/vector?

Comment: How large are the integers in $A,B,\dots,Z$?  Are they always in the range $[0,10^6]$ or so in your application?

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for sharing your idea, its really helpful. Not sets, they're both ordered array. So I guess it is a bit misleading. And regarding the numbers, yes in $[1, 10^6]$ but could have repeating values not necessarily unique values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to guess $a$ (i.e., iterate over all possibilities for it, and the following for each possibility).  Then, you can infer the value of $b$, namely, $b = a r_b/r_a$, so test whether $b \in B$.  Do the same for each of $c,\dots,z$.  If they all work, then you have found a solution; otherwise, proceed on to your next guess at $a$.  This should give you approximately a linear running time if you use the right data structures for storing the vectors (e.g., a hashtable).

A similar approach is to compute the vectors $A/r_a$, $B/r_b$, ..., $Z/r_z$, and then look for an item that occurs in all of those scaled vectors, e.g., using a hashtable or a counter or by sorting and merging the sorted lists.